# AngularJs 2 - Main constractor variables not available of other component templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

This is my main component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './footer.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app/templates/app.component.html',
    directives: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {

    name: string;

    constructor() {

        this.name = 'somename';

    }

}
```

this.name is available as {{name}} in the app template but is not available on my other templates like the header and footer templates.

Here's the header component code:

```
import {
    Component
} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'header-component',
    templateUrl: './app/templates/header-template.html',
})

export class HeaderComponent { }
```

How can I make **{{name}}** value available on other templates?

More details: 
Here's the main app template. Note: Variable IS available here:

```
 <header-component></header-component>
```

```
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Hello {{name}} </p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

But where I want it is here: (The header template)

```
<div>
Hello {{name}} from the header
</div>
```

The above {{name}} does not show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pass it down the line. You didn't show the template but I guess smth like:

```
<header-component [name]="name"></header-component>
```

would be needed. Of course you have to define name as input in HeaderComponent.

Other way would be to create a dummy service and put it into providers entry of component decorator. This would be a singleton in scope of AppComponent and all it's children. Then set it's name property to some value and inject the service into a child component.

Comment: I've updated the question and added more details on the templates.

Comment: variables from parent are not accessible in a child directly. you have to pass them explicitly.

Comment: <header-component [name]="name"></header-component>
and declare inputs: ['name'] in HeaderComponent decorator